# OpenCV CascadeClassifier error

Tags: java, opencv, face-detection

i'm trying to do face detection through a webcam, but i got an error, cascadeclassifier error.

After do some testing, i found this line of code generate the error

```
CascadeClassifier face_cascade = new CascadeClassifier();
```

The error i got is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.CascadeClassifier_0()J
    at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.CascadeClassifier_0(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.<init>(CascadeClassifier.java:38)
    at CamCapture.main(CamCapture.java:24)
```

Is anybody know how to solve this?

---

Comment: You can put the answer as a real answer and accept it I do believe, that way the question gets solved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

finally i found the answer,

i should load the library before use the cascadeclassifier.
so just put this code

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

before the cascadeclassifier.

Comment: It does not work me...Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.CascadeClassifier_1()J
 at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.CascadeClassifier_1(Native Method)

Answer (score 1):

Try initialising CascadeClassifier objects in BaseLoaderCallBack. The OpenCV needs to load completely before initialising the CasCadeClassifier objects.

Place this in onCreate() or onResume():

```
if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug())
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION, this, baseCallBack);
else
    baseCallBack.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
```

define baseCallBack as:

```
private BaseLoaderCallback baseCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        if (status == SUCCESS) {
            try {
                initClassifiers(); // initialise here
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("OpenCVLoad", "OpenCV Loaded");
        } else {
            super.onManagerConnected(status);
        }
    }
};
```