# OpenCV java CascadeClassifier exception

Tags: java, opencv

I'm makeing an eye tracker in java with opencv but when i run this code:

```
CascadeClassifier eye_cascade;

try {
    face_cascade = new CascadeClassifier(PATH + "/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Face cascade not found.");
    return;
}
```

The compiler returns this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.CascadeClassifier_0(Ljava/lang/String;)J

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449781/opencv-cascadeclassifier-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just come up that i have forgotted to import the library:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
}
```